# What is the license of the code generated by Android Studio?

Tags: android

I want to know under which license fall the templates generated by [Android Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Studio).

The code examples that one can find on the Android development site (provided by Google) is Apache v2 - clearly specified.

But when creating for example a new activity based on a template, it is generated without license information.

I've read the Terms and Conditions but there are no details there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Content License](https://developer.android.com/license.html) states:

> This documentation, including any code shown in it, is licensed under the Apache 2.0 license, the preferred license for all parts of the of the Android Open Source Project.

In the Restrictions section, it states the following:

> The use of sample source code provided in the SDK or shown in this documentation is subject to the conditions detailed in the Apache 2.0 license.

You should be safe in assuming that the templates generated by Android Studio are released under the Apache 2.0 license.

To further confirm this, the [Android NDK samples for Android Studio](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk) are explicitly licensed under the Apache 2.0 license.